# how to remove specific form field from validating (is_valid) django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

There are four field in django form and i am using is_valid() function to validate, but instead of validating the whole form i want to exclude one field which should not be validate using is_valid() function

Comment: If you do this, you will probably have SQL error like "NOT NULL constraint failed"...

Answer (score 1):

You can use exclude parameter inside your form to exclude the fields you don't want to get validated.

Let's say you have a model named MyModel and a model form for it named MyForm

```
# forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import MyModel

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel 
        exclude = ['field_name_you_want_to_exclude']
```

Comment: The OP wants the fields to be excluded **from validation**, not removed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clean() method in your model to specify the fields you want to validate https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean